# Одновременные запросы

Tags: php, http, запрос

У меня есть скажем 2 адреса, по которым надо сделать HTTP запросы. Дело в том, что каждый запрос(скрипт куда идет запрос) длится 10 секунд и в итоге скрипт отрабатывает 20 секунд. А как сделать так, чтобы моментально сделать 2 запроса, после чего ожидать 10 секунд оба запроса? Сейчас делаю запрос через `file_get_contents`, но это не принципиально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите информацию [на этом сайте](http://kocherov.net/parallel-curl-parallelnaya-zagruzka-i-obrabotka-stranits-v-php/)

Comment: @Ale_x, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: а зачем копипастить? тем более что вопрос из ряда тех, на который ответ - а что гугл закрылся?

Comment: Не понял, а как curl может помочь запустить асинхронно 2 запроса?

Во второй статье написано

> Можно стартовать хоть 1000 запросов одновременно. Они все складываются в очередь. Выполняется, скажем, 10 одновременно. Как только 1 выполнился, сразу же из очереди берется следующий, а для выполнившегося потока стартует callback функция, переданная параметром

Вот акцент на этом: «Как только 1 выполнился, сразу же из очереди берется следующий». Где тут асинхронность? ТС, скорее, нужно что-то типа этого: [Почти настоящая многопоточность средствами php 5](http://habrahabr.ru/post/75454/)